# Create polygon with Google maps, Open Layers and KML file

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, kml, polygon

I'm trying to make timelined google maps using OpenLayers Timeline open source JavaScript library. (stackoverflow don't allow me to put 3 links, so just google "openlayers-timeline")

my KML file looks like that:

```
<Style id="CALPOST Results 2">
<LabelStyle>
<color>
FF00BEF6
</color>
</LabelStyle>
<LineStyle>
<color>
00000000
</color>
<width>
1
</width>
</LineStyle>
<PolyStyle>
<color>
8000BEF6
</color>
<outline>
0
</outline>
<fill>1</fill>
</PolyStyle>
<BalloonStyle>
<bgColor>
ffffffff
</bgColor>
<text>
<![CDATA[<font size="+1" color="#000000">$[description]</font>]]>
</text>
</BalloonStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
<TimeStamp>
    <when>2011-09-09T20:11:51Z</when>
</TimeStamp>
<name>
Level 8
</name>
<Snippet maxLines="0">
</Snippet>
<styleUrl>
#CALPOST Results 2
</styleUrl>
<Polygon>
<tessellate>
1
</tessellate>
<altitudeMode>
clampToGround
</altitudeMode>
<outerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>
35.0698518412794,32.7952102397171,0
35.0698576233107,32.7956876519707,0
..................................
</coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</innerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

(I've cut out some of the coordinates and other elements to make the post more readable)
The polygon appers great when I load it to clean Google Maps library ([watch here](http://asafcohen.net/testing.html)).
But when I'm using the OpenLayers timeline mention above just red dots appers ([watch here](http://asafcohen.net/openlayers-timeline-master/kml.html)).

Please someone can tell me why it happening?